# create a field in rails 3 + mongo in a model from an array / hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

So lets say I have an array containing a hash like this:

```
[{"head"=> {"title"=>"$20,000 Prize-Winning Chili", 
            "categories"=>[{"cat" => "Tex-mex"}]
```

Its much bigger than this (its a full recipe) - but this should be enough to demonstrate my question.

in my model Recipe.rb I have:

```
  def title
    self["head"]["title"] rescue nil
  end
```

which will give me recipe.title in my views...however, in my controller, I want to be able to do things like:

```
 @recipes = Recipe.where(title: "xyz")
```

But title isn't a field in the collection - so it returns nothing to me... any ideas here? I'm super new to mongo - as in I started with it yesterday.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
@recipes = Recipe.where('head.title' => "xyz")
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
    @recipes = Recipe.where('head.title': "xyz")

Comment: Ah, yes. New syntax is good for symbols only :-) Updated the answer.